# How to get all combinations of array elements after removing each element

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I want to get all combinations of all array elements after removing each element

For example:

input: `[6,5,3,4]`

output should be: `[[5,3,4],[6,3,4],[6,5,4],[6,5,3]]`

Without using any libraries

I worked in this code but did not output the right results

```js
    var arrs = [[]];
    
    function doIt(arr) {
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arrs[i] = arr.filter(function (item) {
                return item != i
            });
        }
    
        console.log(JSON.stringify(arrs));
    }
    
    doIt([4, 3, 1]);
```

Comment: nice idea, do you have tried something?

Comment: Yes , check this https://pastebin.com/ZkuzF0FK

Comment: please add, what you have tried, to the question.

Comment: There's a recursive pattern that you could exploit. The first sublist doesn't have `6` in the beginning but the rest do.

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve] *in the question*.

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also make sure to provide a [mcve].

Comment: "did not output the right results" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? What is the result that you get and why is it the wrong result? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: @JörgWMittag I updated my question with the code I worked in

Comment: I don't see any code in your question. Did you maybe forget to submit your edit?

Comment: I submitted the pastebin url which contains the code - but someone edited it and submitted the code itself , it is submitted now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a nested approach by iterating the given array and map arrays without the element of the outer index.

```js
var array = [6, 5, 3, 4],
    result = array.map((_, i) => array.filter((_, j) => i !== j));

console.log(result);
```

In your code, you need to check against the index of the filter callback instead of the value.

```js
var arrs = [[]];

function doIt(arr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arrs[i] = arr.filter(function (item, j) {
        //                                   ^ use index instead of value
            return j != i;
            //     ^                           here                
        });
    }
    console.log(arrs);
}
doIt([4, 3, 1]);
```

Comment: _"nice idea, do you have tried something?"_ but posting an answer nevertheless...

Comment: Yes - so my code was right , but I just compared with the value not the index - many thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Simple `forEach` + `filter`:**

Just compare the indexes to filter the next element.

```js
var result = [];
var array = [6,5,3,4];
array.forEach((_, i) => result.push(array.filter((_, j) => i !== j)));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This wouldn't work if the array had duplicate elements.

Comment: @AaditMShah oops, my bad.  I need to compare index, answer updated!

Answer (score 0):

No need to complex it, it's realy a simple algorithm.

```js
var input = [6,5,3,4];
var output = [];
for (i = 0; i < input.length; ++i) {
   temp = [];
   for (j = 0 ; j < input.length; ++j) {
      if (i != j)
          temp.push(input[j]);
   }
   output.push(temp);
}
console.log(output);
```

Comment: OP does not ask for output of strings, but for a nested array.

Comment: Did he now? Atm I see it formulated as "output should be"

Comment: And did you notice the brackets and commas in that output? That is a nested array. Compare to how the input looks (which is also an array).